# How to run a command in a folder and subfolder

Tags: perl

I have a large file folder structure with many levels (without a pattern in naming convention). How do I run the following command to extract the data from all the folders? the command is:

```
perl -wne'while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "$&\n"}'inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

It works for one input file, but want it to go through all the text files in folders and subfolders.

Comment: If there are multiple `.txt` files in a sub directory, `outfile.txt` will be overwritten for each file. This does not look like what you want. Please clarify what name you want to save the output as

Answer (score 1):

I'd use find to call Perl with the "-i" option for in-place editing.  With the "-i" option, you can optionally specify an extension for the saved unmodified file; without it, it modifies the file in-place without saving the unmodified file.

```
find dirs -name \*.txt -exec perl -i.orig -wne 'while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "$&\n"}' {} \;
```

or (to start up Perl less often) use:

```
find dirs -name \*.txt -print | xargs perl -i.orig -wne 'while(/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g){print "$&\n"}'
```

Alternatively, you can use the **File::Find** module to walk the directory tree and then do your own in-place editing, but I think the above method is easier if you are on UNIX/Linux.  (If on Windows, you might have to go this way.)